# Can't install Postgres on MacBook M1, Mac OS Monterey 12.4

Tags: postgresql, macos, installation, apple-m1

I have problems installing Postgres on my MacBook M1

The Downloaded Installer is failing (Error in Postprocessing) from [www.enterprisedb.com](http://www.enterprisedb.com) and when I try it with "Port" it is not working (it installs, but doesn't install executables like "pg_ctl")

Is there a solution?

(10 years ago I´ve downloaded the source and compiled it)

Comment: Have you tried installing it with Homebrew? https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql#default

Comment: Postgres.app works for me: https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html

Comment: @ Calling: Since I use traditionell Ports, I didn't tried it with Home-brew, perhaps I should if possible

Comment: @Frank: I was shy using a App, wanted to install it "manually", but if there is no other option I should try this as well

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays I would suggest same like [Calin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320272/cant-install-postgres-on-macbook-m1-mac-os-monterey-12-4#comment127764655_72320272):

### Install using Homebrew

```sh
brew install postgresql
```

As you can see on [brew.sh](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql#default) when searching for *formula* `postgresql` it has binaries (*Bottle*) supporting:

- Apple Silicon (M1) on macOS Monterey

[image: Apple Silicon (M1) is supported]

See also:

- [Installing Postgres via Brew (OSX)](https://gist.github.com/ibraheem4/ce5ccd3e4d7a65589ce84f2a3b7c23a3)
- [Installing Postgres with brew in 2 easy steps – An Integrated World](https://www.anintegratedworld.com/installing-postgres-with-brew-in-2-easy-steps/)
- [postgresql not installed but homebrew reports it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145344/postgresql-not-installed-but-homebrew-reports-it-is)